# Rails: Access parent model attributes in nested model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have `Project` model that `has_many` `tasks`. The `Project` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `validates_associated` `tasks`.

In my `@project` form I'm submitting multiple `tasks` for each `project` in a single submit. I wish to run validations on my nested `tasks` based on the project type. As follows:

`Task` model:

```
  with_options if: :special_project? do |task|
    task.validate :is_possible
  end

  def special_project?
    project.cat == 'special'
  end
```

Unfortunately, Rails gives me a `NilClass` error

`undefined method cat for nil:NilClass`

Apparently the `project_id` attribute has not yet been set in the `Task` model (?).

How do I access a parent `Project` model attributes in my nested `Task` model during validation?

Comment: yes,  has not yet been set

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [inverse_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) for this. By setting `inverse_of` to your models, Rails will use the same record objects in memory when accessing the associated records. Not entirely sure if this will work, but you could try.